# Trouble with finding volume of a solid for $y=2-2x^2, y=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

Here is my problem:

$$y=2-2x^2, y=0$$

I first found points of intersection by solving $y=2-2x^2, y=0$ and found that my points are $-1, 1$

Then I found the area by doing the following:

$$A= \pi r^2$$
$$A=\pi(2-2x^2)^2$$
$$A=64\pi(x^4+1)$$

I then anti-differentiated:

$$64\pi\int_{-1}^{1}(x^4+1)dx$$
$$64\pi(\frac{x^5}{5}+x)|_{-1}^{1}$$

Which I found to be:

$$\frac{768\pi}{5}$$

I exceeded my maximum amount of submission for this problem, but I was wondering if this attempt at the answer is correct or if I made another mistake?

Comment: From the method, it looks like you're talking about a volume of rotation.  Are you sure you rotated around the correct line?

Comment: You're right @aschepler

Comment: $\pi(2-2x^2)^2 = 64\pi(x^4+1)$ for some $x$. But $\pi(2-2x^2)^2=\pi (4-8x^2+4x^4)$ for all $x$

Comment: Graphed the function and $\pi(2-2x^2)^2 \ne 64\pi(x^4+1)$ for all $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are rotating about the $x$-axis. Then the volume of the solid of revolution is
$$\int_{-1}^1\pi(2-2x^2)^2\,dx.$$
Expand. We want 
$$4\pi\int_{-1}^1 (1-2x^2+x^4)\,dx.$$
By symmetry, this is 
$$8\pi\int_0^1 (1-2x^2+x^4)\,dx.$$
An antiderivative is $x-\frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^5$.
When we do the calculation, we end up with $\frac{64\pi}{15}$.

**Remark:** There were errors of algebra in expanding $(2-2x^2)^2$. I do not know where the $64$ came from. The other error came from forgetting the "middle term" when you square $a+b$.

Comment: How come you changed the interval from $-1, 1$ to $0, 1$?

Comment: He was using symmetry; so the integral from -1 to 1 is double the integral from 0 to 1.

Comment: Thank you very much @user84413 but do I need to use this method whenever I have an integral from $-n$ to $n$?

Comment: If you are comfortable with negatives, that's fine. I almost automatically take advantage of symmetry when I see it. You certainly do not *need* to do it.

Answer (score 3):

How do you get that $ \pi (2-2x^2)^2=64 \pi (x^4+1)$? Don't you have $\pi (2-2x^2)^2=4 \pi (1-x^2)^2$?

Answer (score -2):

@T. Bongers

$$
\infty
\quad\mbox{since}\quad
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm d}z \to \infty
$$

$\mathbf{\mbox{ADDENDUM}}$
$$
{\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}}
 \atop
 y < 2 - 2x^{2}\,,\ y>0}\!\!\!\!
\displaystyle{{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z \to \infty\atop }
$$

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, and it's incorrect.

Comment: @T.Bongers See the ADDENDUM.

Comment: That still doesn't resolve the issue, since the relevant region to integrate over is bounded. Have a look at Andre Nicolas' answer. I think you're interpreting the question as a region that's unbounded w.r.t $z$, while it's meant to be about a region rotated around an axis.

Comment: @T. Bongers From the original  question, there is no way to guess the rotation. I agree 1) my answer is not related to the rotation and 2) "with rotation" the solution is finite.